# Windows+Node.js+Socket.io+Express = Mega Lags

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting so much lag when I use the simplest tiny chat app made with node.js+socket.io on a windows computer.

For the first connection to the server app I get near instant responses, but more than 1 connection and suddenly every connection has 1-5 second added delay for every request.

server.js code:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client.html');
});

var userId = 0;
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.userId = userId++;
    Log('New user ID: ' + socket.userId);

    socket.on('chat', function (msg) {
        Log("Data <-> " + socket.userId + ": " + msg);
        io.emit('chat', { id: socket.userId, msg: msg });
    });
});

http.listen(3000, function () {
    Log('Listening on port 3000');
});

function Log(message) {
    var date = new Date();
    var hour = date.getHours(); hour = (hour < 10 ? "0" : "") + hour;
    var min = date.getMinutes(); min = (min < 10 ? "0" : "") + min;
    var sec = date.getSeconds(); sec = (sec < 10 ? "0" : "") + sec;
    var ms = date.getMilliseconds(); ms = (ms < 10 ? "00" : ms < 100 ? "0" : "") + ms;
    console.log(hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec + "." + ms + ": " + message);
}
```

client.html code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
        * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
        body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
        form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
        form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
        form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
        #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
        #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
        #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>
</head>

<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
    function Log(message) {
        var date = new Date();
        var hour = date.getHours(); hour = (hour < 10 ? "0" : "") + hour;
        var min = date.getMinutes(); min = (min < 10 ? "0" : "") + min;
        var sec = date.getSeconds(); sec = (sec < 10 ? "0" : "") + sec;
        var ms = date.getMilliseconds(); ms = (ms < 10 ? "00" : ms < 100 ? "0" : "") + ms;
        console.log(hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec + "." + ms + ": " + message);
    }

    $(function () {
        var socket = io();
        $('form').submit(function () {
            Log("Sent -> " + $('#m').val());
            socket.emit('chat', $('#m').val());
            $('#m').val('');
            return false;
        });
        socket.on('chat', function (data) {
            Log("Received <- " + data.id + ":" + data.msg);
            $('#messages').append($('<li>').text("user#" + data.id + ": " + data.msg));
        });
    });
</script>

<body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
        <input id="m" autocomplete="off" />
        <button>Send</button>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

To test this tiny proof of problem app put both files in same folder, install through npm express and socket.io, execute "node server.js" to start, and connect from a webbrowser to 127.0.0.1:3000 .

For the first connection this gives near instant responses when sending a message, but open another tab in the web browser and suddenly 1-5 second delay gets added to every response. Here's an example showing times logged on my computer:

```
CLIENT -> 15:37:02.244: Sent -> 1
SERVER -> 15:37:04.320: Data <-> 2: 1
CLIENT -> 15:37:04.322: Received <- 2:1
```

As you can see there's a ~2 second delay in that case between the client sending the initial message and the server receiving and processing it, but then there's only 0.002 second delay between the server sending it's reply to the client and the client receiving it.

I figured this might be an issue of configuration with node.js but I installed it only a few days ago and didn't do anything to it so it should still be in it's default configuration, yet just in case I installed node and copied these test files on a second Windows 10 computer but still have the same issue on that second computer.

Anyway, I'm lost, any hint where I could look for a solution to this issue?

Comment: Are you 100% sure you have the same version of socket.io on client and server?

Comment: Yes, because the client is served from the server, so it can't be otherwise.

Comment: Also after a couple hours of trying stuff, looks like forcing transport "polling" instead of "WebSocket" may resolve the issue, which would be extremely unexpected considering i've tested with IE Firefox Chrome on Windows and Firefox on Android. Will do more tests tomorrow and confirm if it still holds.

Comment: I've seen something in a few other posts where people reported a bad version of a webSocket library that is included and used with the server-side socket.io library caused something like this.  Can't remember how it was resolved.  Maybe you can find some other posts talking about that.

Comment: One thing to try on the server: `const io = require('socket.io')({transports: ['websocket'], wsEngine: 'ws'});`.  This switches to the `ws` webSocket engine from the `uws` engine.  I don't know if that engine is installed by default or if it needs to be installed manually.

Comment: I quickly tried to add that transport to both client and server but the client didn't even try to connect with those settings, so probably not installed by default. Gotta go for now but tomorrow I'll try to install it manually and see if it helps.

Comment: You don't use that on the client.  The client is baked in to use the webSocket transport built-into the browser.  You may have to manually install the `ws` module on your server.

Comment: ws is already installed :/

Comment: Just in case i installed the latest version of ws (5.0) and the issue persists